# java directory names in android project

Tags: java, android

I have a library "foo" in my android project. Android studio automatically makes the java directory structure: `foo/java/com/mydomain/foo/`. Since the package name of the library is `com.mydomain.foo`, isn't that enough? Why can't I just put the source code in `foo/java/`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little info about the standard directory structure.  Also see: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html

If you look at the actual files, I would actually expect even more nesting: `foo/src/main/java/com/mydomain/foo`. Are you looking at the actual files or the Android project view in Android Studio?

The standard project structure is `$module/{build,libs,src}/$group/$type/$package`.

- **module**: There can be multiple modules inside a single project. For example, a library and an app, or multiple apps.
- **build, libs, and src**: The source code, xml layouts, and resources are kept under src
- **group**: main, test, androidTest - main is the app, and then tests are separated (and actually build into a separate apk)
- **type**: ex: java, res, assets, manifests - standard java is that everything in the package directory ends up on the classpath. Android has more specialized resource and asset handling, so those are separate.

As you can see, it may seem like lots of extraneous sub-directories, but really they all have a purpose. Android Studio has some views that help to simplify things and show you the important parts of the project.  Also, you may find control(or command)-o and control-shift-o useful to jump to any file you know the name of. When you have a file up on the right side, the little circle with an x in it on the left will show you where that file is in the file tree.

Hope that helps =)

Comment: Yes, Android Studio hides the "src/main" part, so I left it out. I think everything you detail make sense up to `type`. Why after that must it put the full URI package name in the directory structure?

Comment: Once you get under `src/main/java`, it's a typical Java directory structure. Each dot in a package is a new directory. You could have classes from any package, ex a.b.c.AJavaClass. That would be `src/main/java/a/b/c/AJavaClass.java`. That's a Java rule for how packages are structured. You could put your code in default package, but it's not recommended as it could create conflicts when using open source libraries, etc